# Bamboo Plan Branches and Bitbucket Hooks

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo

I have a repository set up with three branches (Dev, QA, Master). I have bamboo set up with the Master branch being the main branch, and then two plan branches for Dev and QA. I have set the build plan to trigger when new commits are pushed. The problem is that when I push code to Dev, it won't trigger the build plan.

I've tried adding hooks into bitbucket but that didn't work either (one hook for each branch), as it triggered all 3 branches to build.  Does anybody know how to set up remote triggers to trigger each branch individually when code is pushed?

Answer (score 1):

I forget the issues i was having with remote triggers, but if it helps, i abandoned that approach and have been very successful in enabling build plan branches and setting Repository Triggers polling every 60 seconds. The polling works well and will detect any changes to any branch and fire off the appropriate build.